Как создать полотно для множественной отрисовки линий на sfml и поместить его в gtk::Box?
работаю с графикой.
Визуальная составляющая проекта написана на gtkmm3.0. Для повышение производительности я подключил sfml к проекту. Проверил работу sfml на sf::RenderWindow и всё работает прекрасно, но по итогу, мне нужно поместить полотно для отрисовки графики в gtk::Box. С окном такое провернуть не получится. Нашёл gtksfml::DrawingArea, но не могу отрисовать на нём ничего. Почитав ещё, понял, что gtksfml::DrawingArea это по сути только контейнер.
Вопрос: Как используя smfl, отрисовывать множество линий и иметь возможность поместить данное полотно в Gtk::Box?
